# Cannot use any Laravel commands? Why is this?

Tags: php, laravel

I have installed Laravel and the requirements need as I would like to use it for my dissertation ideally.

I seem to be having this issue when trying to run any commands in regards to this, and this error is always shown no matter what.

> ```
>  PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/assignment/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed
> ```
>
> to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/assignment/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17 PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/assignment/artisan:0 PHP   2. require()
>   /var/www/assignment/artisan:16 PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed
>   opening required
>   '/var/www/assignment/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in
>   /var/www/assignment/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17 PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/assignment/artisan:0 PHP   2. require()
>   /var/www/assignment/artisan:16

Sorry if formatting is not correct there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Failed opening required bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28468625/laravel-5-failed-opening-required-bootstrap-vendor-autoload-php)

Answer (score 0):

If already installed and putting on production go to your laravel directory and run...

```
composer install
```

Alternatively, if you need update all dependencies run...

```
composer update
```

A good question in more details of when each should be used can be seen on a different question @ [What are the differences between composer update and composer install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052195/what-are-the-differences-between-composer-update-and-composer-install)