# SSH Curl doesn't work when URL is accessible in browser

Tags: curl, command-line, terminal, server, hosting

*This post is linked with another post of mine (<del>still unsolved</del>):*

*[Laravel - composer update: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404280/laravel-composer-update-connection-refused)*

*But I'm making another post about a more specific question.*

---

On SSH, on prod server (shared hosting), I go to a specific folder (which contains my website):

```
$ cd /home/user/www/prod/
```

Then, if I try:

```
$ curl https://larapack.io/packages.json
```

I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to larapack.io port 443: Connection refused
```

But if I do:

```
$ curl https://packagist.org/packages.json
```

It works.

*Note that both files are accessible through my browser.*

---

**I've read several things on forums about *IPv6* or *firewalls*, but:**

- **<del>I don't know if it could cause that</del>**
- **<del>I can't find a proper way to check if both are disabled or not.</del>**

---

### EDIT: Trying other things...

---

**It seems it's not a user agent/referer issue:** (try with chrome 65 on windows 10)

```
$ curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3315.4Safari/537.36" https://larapack.io/packages.json

curl: (7) Failed to connect to larapack.io port 443: Connection refused
```

---

**It seems it's not a IPV6 issue:** (option `-4` to force IPv4)

```
$ curl -4 https://larapack.io/packages.json

curl: (7) Failed to connect to larapack.io port 443: Connection refused
```

---

**It seems it's not a ssl issue:** (option `-k` to skip the ssl things)

```
$ curl -k https://larapack.io/packages.json

curl: (7) Failed to connect to larapack.io port 443: Connection refused
```

---

**It seems it's not a firewall issue:** I have a config file with valid directive `firewall=none`

---

**It doesn't work with `wget`:**

```
$ wget https://larapack.io/packages.json

pathconf: Value too large for defined data type
pathconf: Value too large for defined data type--2018-09-23 13:47:26-- https://larapack.io/packages.json
Resolving larapack.io (larapack.io)... 23.92.17.233
Connecting to larapack.io (larapack.io)|23.92.17.233|:443... 
failed: Connection refused.
```

---

**And neither with `nc` command** (I don't have telnet command, but it works almost the same, as I could read)

```
$ nc larapack.io 443
larapack.io [23.92.17.233] 443 (https) : Connection refused
```

---

**I tried to curl with php, and it works! So it seems it's only with SSH:**

```
<?php

$url = "https://larapack.io/packages.json";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

echo $resp;
```

Comment: Can you telnet to url: larapack.io port ? I mean `telnet larapack.io port 443` ? what is the output

Comment: I get `-ovh_ssh: telnet: command not found`. But I'm on a shared hosting, so I don't know if I can use this command

Comment: @rɑːdʒɑ, I edited my post with all I've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For french developers using SSH with a shared hosting pro at OVH, the support says external calls like `curl` are disabled in ssh, but obviously I can do `curl https://packagist.org/packages.json`.**

**When they tried themselves, they got an error like `action forbidden` or something like that.**

**It doesn't make any sense.**

---

I solved my prior issue doing `composer install` instead of `composer update`.

Here is the first discussion for reference:
[Laravel - composer update: Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52404280/laravel-composer-update-connection-refused)

Answer (score 0):

Just one more thing to check in the case of working browsers but non-working `curl` is in-browser and system proxy settings (`http_proxy`, `https_proxy` environment variables for Linux).