# Use the latest Laravel version

Tags: php, laravel

Lately l've been working with Laravel. I use composer to install packages and artisan for commands.

The problem is that my machine uses Laravel 5.4 not 5.7.

When i run phpinfo() the result is PHP Version 7.2.7. Do you think that the problem is that i don't use the latest version of xampp which it has included php 7?

Comment: For laraver 5.7 you need php version >= 7.1.3

Comment: Try specifying the PHP version like *composer create-project laravel/laravel app "5.7.*"*

Comment: @SuryaNeupane 7.2.7 >= 7.1.3 ;)

Comment: @Anna Jeanine >=7.1.3

Comment: your xampp needs updated php version i think >=7.1.3

Answer (score 3):

Based on comment, yes it is related to PHP version. Your PHP CLI version is too low to support newer version of laravel. You need to update or switch PHP CLI to newer version. Server and CLI PHP are separate packages and might have different versions.

---

No it is not related to PHP version (in this case).

Probably you ran

```
composer install
```

which will install dependencies in versions defined in `composer.lock` to update dependencies run

```
composer update
```

For differences between `install` and `update` you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052195/what-are-the-differences-between-composer-update-and-composer-install)

Comment: - laravel/framework v5.5.9 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.19) does not satisfy that requirement. This i the error i received when i tried to update composer.

Comment: @AstritSpanca Then your PHP CLI is set to PHP 5.6. You need to upgrade your PHP CLI. (This isn't that unusual - they can be totally separate installs versus the webserver.)

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:

> laravel/framework v5.5.9 requires php >=7.0 -> your PHP version (5.6.19) does not satisfy that requirement.

Run `php -i` in the Terminal. Looks like your webserver and your command line (which Composer uses) are using different versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel version depends on your installation way. It's not related to your PHP or XAMPP version. And you are using the latest PHP version, so don't worry about PHP version.

Read the [Laravel installation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7#installation) to install the latest version of laravel.

Answer (score 0):

If you using package laravel/installer

Update this package

```
composer global update
```

and try to run

```
laravel new my-app
```