# Memory error while running the composer update

Tags: php, linux, laravel

Error:

> Updating vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.4.0 => v2.5.1): The following exception
>   is caused by a lack of memory or swap, or not having swap configured
>   Check
>   https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors
>   for details

Currently the AWS Instance RAM: 2GB

Though we have fixed the issue by upgrading RAM from 2GB => 4GB but I have few doubts as increasing RAM this should not be the solution for a small site.

Could you please check the following points:

1) What is the recommended memory required by Laravel for updating the packages (composar.phar update)?

2) Does laravel use SWAP memory as well while composer update?

Comment: Composer is a known memory hog, just check its bugtracker. You will also find a few hints there how to work around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and never found the reason. You could run `composer update --profile` or even `composer update --profile -vvv` to have a detailed list of what's going on under the hood. The first one will show you how much memory is used.

It shouldn't be over 600Mb. But still you will run out of memory. As the laravel app goes into maintenance mode, it shouldn't add to it. You could run in a second shell the command `top -ac` and see what happens there.

The hosting company couldn't help me either as they blamed it on me lol.

But there is a way around. Upload the `composer.lock` only and on the production server run `composer install --no-dev`. It will give you a warning about outdated packages. Answer 'yes' and your prod server will be updated without a glitch. This command runs the laravel `composer.json` scripts commands too and updates the `composer.json` package versions..

Comment: We can try this also, this solved the problem
---------------------------------------------------- 
/bin/dd if=/dev/zero of=/var/swap.1 bs=1M count=1024
/sbin/mkswap /var/swap.1
/sbin/swapon /var/swap.1
----------------------------------------------------

Comment: IF you run into an error (something not found), I had this last week. Run `composer dump-autoload` and the error vanishes.

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, `composer update` is only run on your development environment, when you push your code in AWS server, the command you must use is `composer install` (which doesn't use too much memory).

If you want to know the difference between `update` or `install`, refer to this link: [What are the differences between composer update and composer install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052195/what-are-the-differences-between-composer-update-and-composer-install)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Composer update on the development server and composer install is fine for the first time deployment. But for the next couple of deployments, we have to run composer update means again it will create the issue. Or we have to update the vendor everytime which are quite heavy.

Comment: For the next couple of deployments, ideally you have to always run `composer update` on your development before deploying to your AWS server, push you code in the server, then in your server you run `composer install`. Kindly read my link above, seems that you don't understand the function of `composer install` and `composer update`.

Comment: It doesn't mean that `composer install` is only run on the first time of deployment.