# Laravel after composer install or update

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, fatal-error

As soon i do composer install or composer update, prefere the install as the base script is from 2017. Then i get this.

```
    FatalThrowableError in Inflector.php line 70:
Class 'Doctrine\Inflector\InflectorFactory' not found
in Inflector.php line 70
at Inflector::createFactory() in Inflector.php line 58
at Inflector::getInstance() in Inflector.php line 279
at Inflector::singularize('members') in Pluralizer.php line 77
at Pluralizer::singular('members') in Str.php line 344
at Str::singular('members') in ResourceRegistrar.php line 268
at ResourceRegistrar->getResourceWildcard('members') in ResourceRegistrar.php line 91
at ResourceRegistrar->register('members', 'AdminController', array('names' => array('edit' => 'user.edit', 'destroy' => 'user.destroy'))) in Router.php line 290
at Router->resource('members', 'AdminController', array('names' => array('edit' => 'user.edit', 'destroy' => 'user.destroy'))) in ResourceRegistrar.php line 116
at ResourceRegistrar->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Router))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Router)) in Router.php line 330
at Router->group(array('prefix' => 'panel/admin'), object(Closure)) in ResourceRegistrar.php line 119
at ResourceRegistrar->prefixedResource('members', 'AdminController', array('names' => array('edit' => 'user.edit', 'destroy' => 'user.destroy'))) in ResourceRegistrar.php line 83
at ResourceRegistrar->register('panel/admin/members', 'AdminController', array('names' => array('edit' => 'user.edit', 'destroy' => 'user.destroy'))) in Router.php line 290
at Router->resource('panel/admin/members', 'AdminController', array('names' => array('edit' => 'user.edit', 'destroy' => 'user.destroy'))) in Facade.php line 237
at Facade::__callStatic('resource', array('panel/admin/members', 'AdminController', array('names' => array('edit' => 'user.edit', 'destroy' => 'user.destroy')))) in web.php line 218
at RouteServiceProvider->{closure}(object(Router))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Router)) in Router.php line 330
at Router->group(array('middleware' => 'role'), object(Closure)) in Facade.php line 237
at Facade::__callStatic('group', array(array('middleware' => 'role'), object(Closure))) in web.php line 255
at require('/data01/myserver/htdocs/routes/web.php') in RouteServiceProvider.php line 58
at RouteServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}(object(Router))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Router)) in Router.php line 330
at Router->group(array('middleware' => 'web', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'), object(Closure)) in Facade.php line 237
at Facade::__callStatic('group', array(array('middleware' => 'web', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'), object(Closure))) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 59
at RouteServiceProvider->mapWebRoutes() in RouteServiceProvider.php line 38
at RouteServiceProvider->map()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map'), array()) in Container.php line 508
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'map')) in RouteServiceProvider.php line 69
at RouteServiceProvider->loadRoutes() in RouteServiceProvider.php line 30
at RouteServiceProvider->boot() in RouteServiceProvider.php line 28
at RouteServiceProvider->boot()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot'), array()) in Container.php line 508
at Container->call(array(object(RouteServiceProvider), 'boot')) in Application.php line 769
at Application->bootProvider(object(RouteServiceProvider)) in Application.php line 752
at Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(object(RouteServiceProvider), '18')
at array_walk(array(object(EventServiceProvider), object(RoutingServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(CookieServiceProvider), object(DatabaseServiceProvider), object(EncryptionServiceProvider), object(FilesystemServiceProvider), object(FoundationServiceProvider), object(NotificationServiceProvider), object(PaginationServiceProvider), object(SessionServiceProvider), object(ViewServiceProvider), object(ImageServiceProvider), object(ImageValidatorServiceProvider), object(CashierServiceProvider), object(AppServiceProvider), object(AuthServiceProvider), object(EventServiceProvider), object(RouteServiceProvider), object(TranslationServiceProvider), object(ValidationServiceProvider)), object(Closure)) in Application.php line 753
at Application->boot() in BootProviders.php line 17
at BootProviders->bootstrap(object(Application)) in Application.php line 203
at Application->bootstrapWith(array('Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\DetectEnvironment', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\LoadConfiguration', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\ConfigureLogging', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterFacades', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\RegisterProviders', 'Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders')) in Kernel.php line 254
at Kernel->bootstrap() in Kernel.php line 145
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

And i have no idea why it comes. I tought it was because of the update as then it takes the newest ones and so. But even with the install i get this.

```
Composer.json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
        "intervention/image": "^2.3",
        "cviebrock/image-validator": "^2.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.3.*",
        "laravel/cashier": "~7.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
        "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
        "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*",
        "fahim/laravel5-paypal-ipn": "dev-master@dev",
        "maksekeskus/maksekeskus-php": "v1.4.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
            
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
    "files": [
        "app/helper.php"
       ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

The only thing i can not do is use the php 5.6 as my service provider does not go that low. The oldest one i can use is 7.0

Comment: What version of Laravel are you running?

Comment: Add the composer.json file to your question to check if there's any problem with it

Comment: There's a good reason you should not run `composer update` if not needed :)

Comment: @user1709407 , why are you running `composer update` in the first place?. Are your trying to upgrade your Laravel version?. Which command did you run exactly?. Since both `composer update` and `composer install` serve different purposes.

Answer (score 0):

1. I've compared your `composer.json` file with the official 'JSON' file for your Laravel version and it appears to be in good shape.
   [Original Laravel v5.3.* composer.json file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.3/composer.json)
2. Please only run `composer update` if you have to. Learn about the difference between `composer update` and `composer install` from here. [What are the differences between composer update and composer install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052195/what-are-the-differences-between-composer-update-and-composer-install)
3. From your 'error log' it's complaining about a missing class `Class 'Doctrine\Inflector\InflectorFactory' not found in Inflector.php line 70`.

The file in question resides at `testProject\vendor\doctrine\inflector\lib\Doctrine\Common\Inflector\Inflector.php`. 'testProject' is my project name while trying to reproduce the problem.
Normally, this can easily be fixed by simply adding an `import` statement for the missing 'Class' which in my test case already exists. i.e `use Doctrine\Inflector\InflectorFactory;`
[Original `Inflector.php` file in a fresh installation.](https://pastebin.com/CYE4jm7v)

❌Since its generally bad practice to manually edit files in the `vendor` folder  that reside in your project root directory, below is my suggestion.

## Procedure

1. Delete your `composer.lock` file from your project root directory.
2. Delete the whole `vendor` folder  from your project root directory.
3. Open your terminal/PowerShell, ➡ navigate to your project root directory, ➡ run the command `composer clear-cache`
   This will delete all content from Composer's cache directories.
4. Open your terminal/PowerShell, ➡ navigate to your project root directory, ➡ run the command `composer update`
   Wait for 'composer' to write a new lock file and to install the fresh dependencies.
   Make sure the file `app/helper.php` exists since I saw it in your customized `composer.json` file.
   I had to remove that [declaration below](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files) from the customized `composer.json` file since I didn't have access to the `app/helper.php` file while testing.

```
// ...
,
    "files": [
        "app/helper.php"
       ]
// ...
```

5. If the 'update' is successful, all should be well.
   In your project root directory, you can run the command `php artian serve` and navigate to the displayed output URL in your browser to confirm if the error has disappeared.